# I don't know where my String index out of range: 0 error is coming from

Tags: java, arrays

I'm trying to take data out of a txt file and create comparable objects out of the data and add them to an array. After that array is created, I want to make a 2d array that stores a 1 in a slot if two options meet the requirements. I keep getting a String index out of range: 0 error though and I do not know where it comes from.

```
 import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class CourseScheduler
{

public int numberOfCourses;
public int[][] adjacent;
public Course[] courses;

public CourseScheduler(String filename)
{
  File file = new File(filename);

  try{
     Scanner scan = new Scanner(file);
     numberOfCourses = scan.nextInt();
     courses = new Course[numberOfCourses];
     adjacent = new int[numberOfCourses][numberOfCourses];

     scan.useDelimiter(",|\\n");
     for(int i = 0; i < numberOfCourses;i ++){
        if(scan.hasNext()){
           String dept = scan.next();
           String num = scan.next();
           String building = scan.next();
           String room = scan.next();
           String instruct = scan.next();

           courses[i] = new Course(dept, num, building, room, instruct);
        }
     }
  }



  catch(FileNotFoundException ex){
     System.out.println("File was not found");
  }


  for(int x = 0;x<numberOfCourses;x++){
     for(int y = 0;y<numberOfCourses;y++){
        adjacent[x][y] = (courses[x].compare(courses[y]));
     }
  }
```

}

This is the code for the main class

```
public class Course{

String department;
String courseNum;
String buildingCode;
String roomCode;
String instructorName;

public Course(String dept, String number, String building, String room,    String instructor){
  department = dept;
  courseNum = number;
  buildingCode = building;
  roomCode = room;
  instructorName = instructor;
   }

   public String getDept(){
  return department;
  }

 public String getCourse(){
  return courseNum;
 }

 public String getBuilding(){
  return buildingCode;
 }

 public String getRoom(){
  return roomCode;
 }

 public String getInstructor(){
  return instructorName;
 }

 public String toString(){
  return department + ";" + courseNum + ";" + buildingCode + ";" + roomCode    + ";" + instructorName;
  }
   public int compare(Course comp){
  int ans = 1;
  String compNum = comp.getCourse();

  if(instructorName == comp.getInstructor())
     ans = 0;

  if(buildingCode == comp.getBuilding()){
     if(roomCode == comp.getRoom())
        ans = 0;
  }
  if(department == comp.getDept()){
     if(courseNum.charAt(0) == compNum.charAt(0))
        ans = 0;
  }

  return ans;
}
}
```

this is the code for the course class

Comment: Couple of things: You're comparing Strings with `==`, but should be using `.equals()` instead. Also, a debugger is really helpful with these sorts of issues.

Comment: why dont you post stacktrace as well?

Comment: Why don't you use a debugger, step through the code, and find exactly where it comes from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Educated guess: Most likely your error is coming from this line:

```
 if(courseNum.charAt(0) == compNum.charAt(0))
    ans = 0;
```

Either courseNum or compNum are empty.

Comment: I agree that this is where the error is coming from after looking at the debugger. Do you see why on earth it would be empty though?

Comment: @Sannesh Your input file contains empty fields?

Comment: The input file is:

Comment: 10

BUSN,1001,HANN,'109,Babin L

MRKT,3002,HMPH,'124,Babin L

MRKT,3011,HMPH,'124,Babin L

CINS,3044,HMPH,'318,Barnett W

CINS,4030,HMPH,'318,Barnett W

RMIN,3008,HMPH,'113,Berry C

RMIN,3020,HMPH,'113,Berry C

ACCT,3008,HMPH,'222,Boswell K

ACCT,4020,HMPH,'222,Boswell K

CONS,2011,CONS,'126,Bray H

Comment: @Sannesh Please edit you question to include the input file properly formatted.

Comment: Sorry about that. I actually got it working. I had to rework my delimiter to work with a notepad newline character instead of just \n. Thank you so much for your help

Answer (score 0):

I did not try to compile and run it but its seems that the exception comes from this line

```
if(courseNum.charAt(0) == compNum.charAt(0))
```

If a string is empty, charAt(0) will throw exactly the given exception.

Tip: if you don't know how to use a debugger, use the old fashioned System.out.println(). Put println() here and there in your code to understand how it works.